# Space-efficient proof environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

I want to customize Beamer so that each theorem statement begins to the right of the word "Theorem" instead of below it, and similarly so that and each proof begins to the right of the "Proof." demarcation instead of on the next line.  Somehow (not sure how) I figured out how to do this in the case of theorem-like environments; my solution uses this code:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\vspace{1ex}%
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}\usebeamerfont*{block title}
  \inserttheoremname\ %
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  } \normalfont }
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\vspace{0ex}} % Okay because we have \parskip
\makeatother
```

However, I am lost as to what to do for the proof environment.  In fact the standard proof environment has gotten even less space efficient for me, I think since I am redefining \parskip.  If someone could help me with this, that would be great.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Could you please add a small compilable document that shows how you use this stuff? This will allow us to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof that it is very hard to give a meaningful answer without a minimal working example (MWE). Continuing what you did and putting it into a minimal document yields

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{\vspace{1ex}%
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}\usebeamerfont*{block title}
  \inserttheoremname\ %
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  } \normalfont }
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\vspace{0ex}} % Okay because we have \parskip
\setbeamertemplate{proof begin}{\vspace{0.5ex}%
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}\usebeamerfont*{block title}%
\insertproofname\ }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{proof end}{\par
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A theorem}
\begin{theorem}
 Something.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
 Obvious.
\end{proof}
Some more blabla.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Fermat's last theorem]
 There is no integer solution to
 \[x^n +y^n=z^n\] 
 for integers $n>2$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
 The proof is left as an exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}
Some more quack quack.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would say this is very space efficient, maybe even too much.

However, you mention that you have problems:

> ... has gotten even less space efficient for me, I think since I am
>   redefining `\parskip`

OK, great, but if others do not know what you did precisely, how can they make sure that the solution they come up with really works for you? 
QED.

Comment: If you use `\setbeamertemplate{proof end}{\\
}` then there will be no space even if you have a huge `\parskip`. Yet there will be better solutions if one has an MWE.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   Even if I did not follow best practices in setting up the question, your answer is super helpful.  I think that I can work with this.

Comment: Also to answer your question, I have `\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}`.